# Is it possible to have 2 datasources for ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to have

```
<tbody ng-repeat="Emp in Employees"  ng-repeat="Dept in Department">

    <td> <span>{{Emp.id}}</span></td>
    <td> <span>{{Emp.name}}</span></td>
     <td> <span>{{Dept.Deptid}}</span></td>

 </tbody>
```

That means two different sources.... It is for a composite UI requirement. If not available, what is the alternate way?

I am not looking for

```
<tbody ng-repeat="Emp in Employees" >

    <td> <span>{{Emp.id}}</span></td>
    <td> <span>{{Emp.name}}</span></td>

</tbody>

<tbody ng-repeat="Dept in Department">

      <td> <span>{{Dept.Deptid}}</span></td>
       <td> <span>{{Dept.Deptname}}</span></td>                                

</tbody>
```

Something similar to LINQ in C# like

```
var x = (from a in AList
          join b in BList on a.item = b.item
          select new{....});
```

Comment: How are organize the data ?

Comment: You can create a composite object that combines the two (maybe called `employeeDepartment` )and ng-repeat on that.  I suggest writing logic similar to your LINQ in your javascript to make a composite object.

Comment: @ryanyuyn.. this I cannot do. Let me say that I am trying to implement the SERVICE concept of Mr. Udi Dahan, if I have understand that properly.So far the Composite UI is concern. This idea already came to my mind, but I cannot do

Comment: Where's the connection between an employee and a department? Does an `Employe` object have a `departmentId` property? Furthermore in your LINQ example you essentially create a new datasource! You'll have to do that in your Angular code as well.

Comment: @zeroflag yes sir you are right. I again went thru the videos of Mr. Udi and followed many other blogs and came to know that my understanding was wrong. I am rectifying my model and then again try. Thank you Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by merging two arrays

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.Employees = [{
    'id':1,
    'name':'rachit1'
  },
  {
    'id':2,
    'name':'rachit2'
  }];
  $scope.Department=[{
    'Deptid':'1D',
    'Deptname':'dep1'
  },
  {
    'Deptid':'2D',
    'Deptname':'dep2'
  }];
  $scope.result=merge($scope.Employees,$scope.Department);

  function merge(obj1,obj2){ // Our merge function
    var result = {}; // return result
    for(var i in obj1){      // for every property in obj1 
        if((i in obj2) && (typeof obj1[i] === "object") && (i !== null)){
            result[i] = merge(obj1[i],obj2[i]); // if it's an object, merge   
        }else{
           result[i] = obj1[i]; // add it to result
        }
    }
    for(i in obj2){ // add the remaining properties from object 2
        if(i in result){ //conflict
            continue;
        }
        result[i] = obj2[i];
    }
    return result;
}
});
```

HTML:-

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <table>
       <tbody ng-repeat="Emp in result">
    <td> <span>{{Emp.id}}</span></td>
    <td> <span>{{Emp.name}}</span></td>
     <td> <span>{{Emp.Deptid}}</span></td>
     <td> <span>{{Emp.Deptname}}</span></td>

 </tbody>
     </table>
  </body>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mTK5csCaKHd5uuBBDZ7V?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :Can't. Because may the looping count is difference.

can you write a looping statement on a  another one looping statement?

```
for (var i=0;i<Empcount;i<DeptCount;i++)
{
// code

}
```

Is it impossible, Same as what the answer for your question. You can think the result.

Comment: I don't know who has downvoted, but he cleared my understanding....I am upvoting u. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is not really an answer, but I must to say this: your data organised incorrectly. Data integrity is violated.

But if you can't change the source structure for some reason try to combine that data in the controller:

```
$scope.employees = employees.map(function (employee, index) {
   employee.department = departments[index];

   return employee;
})
```

Then use it in the `ng-repeat`:

```
<tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
      <td>{{ employee.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ employee.department.deptId }}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

**NOTES:**

- Do not repeat `<tbody>` tag.
- Apply the technique if `Departments.length === Employees.lengh` and the order is correct.
- Do not capitalize not constructors. Rename `Departments` to `departments`, `Employees` to `employees`.
- If you don't have any styles on `td > span` then remove unnecessary span's